# What's wrong with this thermodynamics argument on the cosmological constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, space-expansion, cosmological-constant

I'm puzzled by the following thermodynamics argument on the cosmological constant interpreted as a perfect fluid of pressure $p = -\, \rho$.  I start considering a simple fluid of local energy density $\rho$, local pressure $p$ and local temperature $T$.  The energy of a fluid element of volume $V$ is $E = \rho \, V$.  I'm considering the fluid's entropy as a function of the independant variables $T$ and $V$:  $S(T, V)$ (instead of the usual $S(E, V)$).  Since $dE = \rho \, dV + V \, d\rho$, the thermodynamics first law $dE = T \, dS - p \, dV$ give two equations (this part is easy to verify):
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} &= \frac{V}{T} \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial T}, \tag{1} \\[2ex]
  \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} &= \frac{V}{T} \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial V} + \frac{\rho + p}{T}. \tag{2}
 \end{align}
Of course:
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial V \, \partial T} = \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial T \, \partial V},
 \end{equation*}
which implies a constraint on the three functions $\rho(T, V)$, $p(T, V)$ and $S(T, V)$ (this second part is also easy to check):
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} = \frac{V}{T} \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial V} + \frac{\rho + p}{T} \equiv \frac{\partial S}{\partial V}. \tag{3}
 \end{align}
Next, I substitue the equation of state usually associated to the cosmological constant: $p = -\, \rho$.  The previous differential equation then give
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} = -\, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial T} = \frac{V}{T} \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial V} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad T \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial T} = - \, V \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial V}. \tag{4}
 \end{align}
This last equation implies $\rho = f(V/T)$, where $f(u)$ is an arbitrary function of the variable $u = V / T \sim \mathrm{L}^4$ (I'm using units such that $c = 1$, $\hbar = 1$ and $k_{\text{B}} = 1$).  The entropy can then be found by integrating equations (1) and (2) ($\mathcal{C}$ is an arbitrary integration constant, which isn't important here):
\begin{equation}
  S = g(u) = \int u' \, \frac{d f}{du'} \: du' + \mathcal{C}. \tag{5}
 \end{equation}
The last part is what puzzles me.  In cosmology, the cosmological constant defines the fluid's energy density, which is constant in time:
\begin{align}
  \rho = \frac{\Lambda}{8 \pi G} = \text{cst}. \tag{6}
 \end{align}
This density does not depend on the volume or the temperature.  Since the thermodynamics argument above give $\rho = f(V/T)$ and $S = g(V/T)$, it implies that the temperature should rise with the volume: $T \propto V \propto a(t)^3$ (where $a(t)$ is the cosmological scale factor).  The cosmological constant fluid rises its temperature while the space expansion is going on (which is really weird!), and the entropy stays the same (as it should, for a perfect fluid in cosmology).  This counter-intuitive result is not so surprising after all, since the cosmological constant isn't a normal "fluid", considering its weird equation of state $p = -\, \rho$.  So I have two questions:

1. What's wrong with this thermodynamics argument?
2. If there's nothing wrong with it, how can we find the function $f(u)$, without assuming (6) (that the energy density is a constant)?  What is missing?

Notice that the variable $u$ has dimensions $\mathrm{L}^4$, while the energy density has dimensions $\rho \sim \mathrm{L}^{-4}$, so maybe $f(u) = \frac{k}{u} = k T/V$ (where $k$ is a pure numerical constant).  In this case, the energy of a given volume $V$ of fluid is $E = \rho V = k \, T$ and the entropy is given by (5) (without assuming (6)):
$$\tag{7}
S(u) = \ln ( \lambda^4 \, T/V )^k + \text{cst},
$$
where $\lambda \sim \mathrm{L}$ is some arbitrary length scale constant.  This entropy is similar to the Boltzmann expression $S = \ln \Omega$.  However, from gravity and the cosmological constant, there are two scales that could be introduced here: $G \sim \mathrm{L}^2$ (or Planck's length) and $\Lambda \sim \mathrm{L}^{-2}$ (a cosmological scale), so the function $f(u)$ isn't unique.

Comment: This might be a super trivial question, but it never hurts to check: does the fact that energy is not conserved break any of the thermodynamic arguments?

Comment: @Javier, this remark doesn't seem trivial to me!

Comment: @Javier, the energy may not be conserved even in classical thermodynamics, since we're considering the energy of an element of fluid (of volume $V$), which isn't a closed system.  It is surrounded by all the rest of the Universe.

Comment: If spacetime is curved, then you cannot write $E=ρV$. Incidentally, if you are considering cosmology, $V$ is not a natural variable for thermodynamic in this context since you cannot control volume of the universe.

Comment: @A.V.S., the expression $E = \rho V$ is frequently used in standard cosmology (for the local conservation of energy), even if space is curved (space and matter are homogeneous).  The variable $V$ isn't the volume of the whole universe, it's just the volume of a given part of the homogeneous fluid, which is expanding since $V \propto a^3$.

Comment: And my question is more about what thermodynamics may have to say for a fluid of equation of state $p = -\, \rho$.  What can we learn about the cosmological constant, from a thermodynamical point of view?

Comment: Ah, so you are not looking for an energy of universe (or of static de Sitter patch)? Then consider that $∂ρ /∂V \equiv 0 $, then one interpretation of your eq. (4) is that $T=0$. and you have a lot of either trivial $0=0$ equations or $0/0$ indeterminate forms.

Comment: Does a perfect cosmological constant fluid have a temperature? Normally I'd associate it with the vacuum and zero temperature.

Comment: @Andrew, well, that's part of the problem.  Usually, $T = 0$ for a pure void.  We usually also assume $T = 0$ for the cosmological constant (constant density of the vacuum).  But thermodynamics give another solution: $T \propto V$.  So is there a way to determinate the function $f(u)$ from thermodynamical (maybe statistical) considerations?

Comment: I see. I suspect your equations are indeterminate because you can't really differentiate with respect to the temperature of the vacuum. I think I agree with @A.V.S. that $\partial \rho / \partial V$ is $0$ that will end up leading to other problems.